# Service Design in an Organization with different products

Tags: ux-integration, product-management, service-design

Upon learning a service design and trying to see how it would be implemented in an organization, I come up with a question.

Supposed a medium sized organization have  different products exposed to the user, i.e:

1. Consultation Service
2. Ecommerce
3. Service Booking

as per my understanding to service design, we ought to break the silo in order for customers to have "smooth" experience when using a certain product. These 3 products, do have their own Manager to manage the operation, now my question would related on what's the role of these manager in service design team.

I always assume that UX and Product team are the support ecosystem to make sure these products well adapted by the user in their usage of the product but then in this organization, there are silos with (ridiculously enough) egocentric necessities, thus put product and UX team kinda in a pinch between each manager's goals. I was thinking that a service design would be great to be implemented to break the silo, and implementing service design would require an organizational change on how they typically would work and see how thinks work.

so basically I wonder how to deal with this situation, more accurately what role does all these manager really are. Do they actually act as product owner? Do the product management team include this managers as part of the team? or these managers are actually the product managers? (which they're not currently)

Please feel free to edit my question since I'm also in the mid of confusion when I craft this scenario based on my colleagues problem in his company (he's a product manager)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question, in any case, if there were, it belongs to [Project Management SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Danielill thank you for the reminder, smh I forgot to include the question. otoh, so this topic belong to another SE? I thought since it's related to UX and Product Management I could post it here sorry

Comment: This is a great question. While certainly related to UX, I agree with @Danielillo that something like Project Management SE (which I didn't know existed) will probably be a better place to get more answers. But I'm quite curious about those answers as well

Comment: OK then if that's how it should be I would post this topic on project management SE, as I also feel that at some stage I feel this is more like product management + organizational topic

Comment: @Elie I would say that this is indeed an organisational structure topic because this is usually how the different departments, teams and roles are created to support the products and services. But from a pure definition perspective, service design should span the breadth of the service, so whether or not the organisational structure is created so that silos are formed or not, the service designer should bridge these gaps and build a consistent and coherent flow.